# The meaning of "send round my kit"

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

> He was silent for a few moments evidently thinking of what he could do
>   for Srebnitz.  Then he said "Tell your mother and father to change
>   their minds while there is still time. Now I will go and **send round
>   my kit**."

This is from "Guerrilla" by Lord Dunsany.

He is a German major billeted in a house in a neighbor country. And he is satisfied with the hospitality  of the family.

I do not understand the meaning of "send round my kit."

Answer (score 2):

> **[kit](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/kit)** (n): 1.1 (British) A set of articles forming part of a soldier's equipment.

To "send [something] around" means "to have [something] brought [to someone]".  While I don't think the expression is *exclusively* British, it is more British than it is American.

It's unclear what the officer expects done to his "kit" when he "sends it around" to them, but, if I had to guess, likely he expects them to wash, mend, and iron his uniform and other articles of clothing.  Perhaps there's more information in the next paragraph?

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer! It is  so helpful. There is any more information about it in after paragraph. But your answer is enough for me.

Comment: "kit" = equivalent of his luggage/personal items, often kept in a duffel bag or some sort of backpack.

Comment: [Pack Up Your Troubles in Your Old Kit Bag and Smile, Smile, Smile](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pack_Up_Your_Troubles_in_Your_Old_Kit-Bag)